# flutter_blue is not working in release apk (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, iot

While debugging the app Bluetooth is scanning and identifying near by devices. In release mode, it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code in [Project-Name]/android/app/build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            shrinkResources false    // this line
            minifyEnabled false       // this line
        }
    }
```